# Why does OpenMP not speed up this code?

Tags: c++, openmp

To practice OpenMP I decided to write an algorithm to row reduce a matrix.  Surprisingly when I added and #pragma omp parallel for to my inner loop there was no noticeable speed gain despite the fact that my program spends 99% of its time in that inner loop.  I was not expecting to see a 4x performance gain on my quad core i7 but I did expect to see something.

```
void Matrix::row_reduce(dim_t eff_width)
{   
    if(eff_width == 0 || eff_width > w)
        eff_width = w;

    dim_t* leads = new dim_t[h];

    double t1 = omp_get_wtime();

    for(dim_t r1 = 0; r1 < h; r1++)
    {
        dim_t lead = 0;
        double* ptr1 = (*this)[r1];
        while(lead < eff_width && ptr1[lead] == 0)
            ++lead;

        leads[r1] = lead;

        if(lead == eff_width)
            continue;
        //makeing this for parallel has no effect in speed
        #pragma omp parallel for
        for(dim_t r2 = 0; r2 < h; r2++)
        {
            if(r2 == r1)
                continue;

            if((*this)[r2][lead] == 0)
                continue;

            double scale = -(*this)[r2][lead] / ptr1[lead];
            add_scaled_row(r2, r1, scale);
            (*this)[r2][lead] = 0;
        }
    }
    t1 = omp_get_wtime() - t1;

    double t2 = omp_get_wtime();
    for(dim_t r = 0; r < h; r++)
    {
        if(leads[r] < eff_width)
            scale_row(r, 1.0 / (*this)[r][leads[r]]);
    }
    t2 = omp_get_wtime() - t2;

    double t3 = omp_get_wtime();
    for(dim_t i = 0; i < h; i++)
    {
        dim_t min = i;
        for(dim_t j = i + 1; j < h; j++)
        {
            if(leads[min] > leads[j])
                min = j;
        }
        if(min != i)
        {
            dim_t tmp = leads[i];
            leads[i] = leads[min];
            leads[min] = tmp;
            swap_rows(min, i);
            printf("SWAP\n");
        }
    }
    t3 =  omp_get_wtime() - t3;

    double total = t1 + t2 + t3;
    printf("t1 = %lf\t%lf\n", t1, 100 * t1 / total);
    printf("t2 = %lf\t%lf\n", t2, 100 * t2 / total);
    printf("t3 = %lf\t%lf\n", t3, 100 * t3 / total);

    delete[] leads;
}
```

The inner loop here is kind of obviously parallel.  The leading term can be eliminated from each row completely independently.  I am thinking that maybe there is no performance gain because the bottle neck is memory but I still would expect a slight performance boost.

Also if anyone is interested here is my add_scale_row function.

```
void Matrix::add_scaled_row(dim_t dest_r, dim_t src_r, double f)
{
    if(dest_r == src_r)
    {
        scale_row(dest_r, 1.0 + f);
        return;
    }
    double* __restrict__ s = (*this)[src_r];
    double* __restrict__ d = (*this)[dest_r];

    __m256d vf = _mm256_set1_pd(f);

    for(dim_t i = 0; i < w; i += 4)
    {
        __m256d a = _mm256_load_pd(s + i);
        __m256d b = _mm256_load_pd(d + i);
        b = _mm256_fmadd_pd(a, vf, b);
        _mm256_store_pd(d + i, b);
    }
}
```

I also checked inside my loop by calling omp_get_num_threads and it gives my 8 (4 cores X 2 hyperthreads).  Also I checked in my system monitor and it seems to show all cores running at 100% when I run this.  I am using GCC 4.9 on Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: Have you tried to ensure your threads are doing any work. Try and make a `cout` with the thread id/number?. You can also try and use the `num_thread` clause in your `#pragma omp ...`

Comment: In system monitor all threads are at 100 percent

Comment: Yes, but they might just be running and not doing anything, i.e. openmp starts them up, but they never do any work. If you don't see any speedup, either the overhead is to big, or the threads are not doing any work.

Comment: Also, did you remember to build with `-fopenmp`?

Comment: Yes.  It would not max out my cpus in the system monitor if I didn't

Comment: Try to print out the thread id from the loop in the parallel region then. `cout << omp_get_num_threads() << endl;` Just to ensure the threads get in there.

Comment: Did you try to move #pragma omp parallel ahead of r1 loop, while keeping #pragma omp for before r2 loop? Also could you try to slightly simplify samplecode to make it easier to read (for stackoverflow) and to triage/investigate (for yourself)?  It would also be interesting to know values of "h" as well as output for t1.

Comment: Well the outer loop can not be done in parallel.

Comment: I suggest you trying performance tools (such as Paraver http://www.bsc.es/computer-sciences/performance-tools/paraver) to explore the performance of this code.